# How can one see the true MAC address of a bridged system

Tags: networking, mac-address, bridge

I know the MAC addresses of the systems in my wired LAN and can see them with Fing or arp-scan. One system runs hostapd as a bridged WiFi router. This latter system shows as having a totally different MAC address. As I understand it, this address is created when the bridge is set up. Is there a way to set up the bridge or to use utilities such as arp-scan or Fing to report the true MAC code? [Please leave aside issues about spoofing of MAC addresses.]

There is no problem getting the information with Ansible or similar tools but they need to be logged-in, whereas Fing etc can get the data without requiring authentication.

========= further information added below =========

The equipment I am describing as a "bridge" is a Raspberry Pi3b+ with a single ethernet interface and a built in WiFi interface. It runs Raspberry Pi OS "Buster" which is a Debian derivative. The bridge is configured using systemd-networkd:
/etc/systemd/network/bridge-br0.netdev contains

```
[NetDev]
Name=br0
Kind=bridge

/etc/systemd/network/br0-member-eth0.network contains
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
Bridge=br0
```

After stripping out comments and blocks of blank lines, /etc/dhcpcd.conf contains

```
hostname
clientid
persistent
option rapid_commit
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
option interface_mtu
require dhcp_server_identifier
slaac private
## key items follow ##
denyinterfaces wlan0 eth0
interface br0
```

The key items being the denyinterfaces and interface lines.

As noted in the original post, the system runs hostapd. The hostapd.conf file contains the lines

```
interface=wlan0
bridge=br0
```

This works correctly as a WiFi bridge, enabling the WiFi kit around my home to share the same subnet as the wired kit.

on the system described, the output from ipaddr show is

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 11:22:33:44:55:66 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 [redacted]/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 77:88:99:aa:bb:cc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.178.226/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute br0
       valid_lft 62947sec preferred_lft 48912sec
    inet6 [redacted]/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dd:ee:ff:00:11:22 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 [redacted]/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

MAC addresses have been changed or redacted
Fing or arp-scan run from other machines on the subnet associate the system's IP address with the MAC address 77:88... associated with interface br0 rather than the 11:22... address associated with eth0.

While checking my installation against the Debian Wiki https://wiki.debian.org/SystemdNetworkd and some other sites, I found the following text:

> Hint: in Debian Buster (probably also previous versions) systemd-networkd may assign a different MAC-Address to the bridge than your physical interface has. This may cause connection issues if your service provider uses some kind of MAC-filtering when routing your traffic. To circumvent such problems you may assign a MAC-address to your bridge (probably the same as your physical device, replace the 'xx' with valid MAC):

```
  [NetDev]
  Name=br0
  Kind=bridge
  MACAddress=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

I hope to test this over the next few days. It won't answer the primary quesion but it will allow a rather kludgy circumvention.

Comment: I think you are confused. Every interface has its own MAC address. There is not a single "true" MAC address.

Comment: Absolutely. The interface must have its own address. When, however, you have a bridged device, arp-scan shows the bridge address, not the hardware address.

Comment: There is no single bridge MAC addressor MAC address for a device; MAC addresses are interface addresses. For example, a Cisco switch will have a MAC address on every physical interface, and it has 1024 MAC addresses from which you get MAC addresses  for each virtual interface you create. There is no one MAC address of the switch; they are all equal MAC addresses of the switch.